# How do I protect my app backend server and api key from being stolen?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

So I have this android app which runs on backend server using a server and api key as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

```
public class AppConfig {

//your server key and rest api key which obtained from the admin panel
public static final String SERVER_KEY = "my server key";
public static final String REST_API_KEY = "rest api key";
```

these keys can be taken from the backend server only. Apparently some developer decompiled my app apk file and stole the keys from there and put it in their own app which is the same as mine. Now as they have the keys, their app is showing whatever I have added in the backend server for my app, when I do changes to my backend server the changes are showing in their app as well. is there any way to protect these keys from getting stolen when someone use a decompiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your keys in the **application.properties** file. And then you can add **application.properties** to the .gitignore file to prevent it from getting uploaded to GitHub.
Or else you can store it in a .env file and add it to the .gitignore file.

---

You can refer to this link to use .env : https://github.com/cdimascio/dotenv-java
video tutorial: https://youtu.be/o1HsGbTZObQ

Comment: It's an android studio app made with java and xml, Is there a way to use .env variables in Android (java)?

Comment: I've mentioned in answer